# Node.js multer unable to store files and string data

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using Node.js and multer to store files but am unable to save them.

From the React side, I send data in formdata using post request, browser is showing files and data, node receives the request and in the req.files I get the file as well.

I tried upload.any(), upload.array(), but nothing shows the file in req.file or req.files. When I try upload.single("filename"), console shows the data.

I have checked the req.files – it shows:

```
  name: '783px-Test-Logo.svg.png',
  data: <Buffer 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52 00 00 03 0f 00 00 01 67 08 06 00 00 00 e0 e4 75 c8 00 00 11 22 33 41 4d 41 00 00 b1 8f 0b fc 61 05 00 ... 18403 more bytes>,
  size: 18453,
  encoding: '7bit',
  tempFilePath: '',
  truncated: false,
  mimetype: 'image/png',
  md5: '6a78913c131cfcd539813bd4b7c42459',
  mv: [Function: mv]
}
```

So I am getting files here from the browser, but the problem is that it is creating an empty storage folder.

These are my multer configurations:

````
const userTypes = require("../internal/users/consts/userTypes");
const middlewares = require("../api/middlewares");
const AssignmentsApi = require("../api/assignment");
const multer = require('multer');


let storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './storage')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname + '-' + Date.now())
    }
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

module.exports = app => {
    const assignmentRouter = express.Router();
    assignmentRouter.use(middlewares.AuthMiddleware);
    assignmentRouter
        .route("/uploadnew")
        .post(middlewares.UserRolesMiddleware(userTypes.teacher),  upload.any(), function(req, res, next) {
            if (req.file) {
                console.dir("req.file", req.file);
                console.log("uploadnew files", req.file.assignmentFile);
                return res.end("Thank you for the file");
            } else if (req.files) {
                console.dir("req.files", req.files);
                console.log("uploadnew files", req.files.assignmentFile);
                return res.end("Thank you for the files");
            }
            res.end("Missing file");
        }); 
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

As I could see, you didn't used **path.join(...)** Use the snippet like this (see from 6-th line) below.
Just replace with your folder relative path right, and override the stuff you want.

```
const path = require('path');

multer({
    storage: multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, cb) {
            // IMPORTANT: don't forget to use path.join(....)
            const filePath = path.join(__dirname, `./storage`);
            cb(null, filePath);
        },
        filename: (req, file, cb) => {
            const extension = file.mimetype.split('/')[1];
            const dateField = (new Date().getTime() / 1000 | 0);
            const randomField = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);
            const fileName = `${dateField}-${randomField}.${extension}`;
            return fileName;
        },
    }),
    limits: {
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 10 // MB
    },
    fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
        let isValid = (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' ||
                       file.mimetype === 'image/jpg' ||
                       file.mimetype === 'image/png');
        cb(null, isValid);
    },
});
```

Make sure you have the same "filename" in your HTML. For example for multiple image uploading you need to have something like this

```
<input type="file" name="filename" multiple>
```

And the middleware should looks like this:

```
router.post('/upload-images', upload.array('filename', 10), (req, res) => { ... });
```

Note: for seeing the uploaded files, don't forget to define the public URL for them before this (for example):

```
app.use('/storage', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'storage')));
```

Comment: i have tried it. but it didnt worked out for me!

Comment: one more thing to mention here, i am using docker container (ubuntu) and accessing node code using wsl (Windows), is there anything to do with that?

Comment: I don't think that it could depends from containerization. Just make sure you have the same "filename" in your HTML. For example for multiple image uploading you need to have something like this: <input type="file" name="filename" multiple> and upload.array('filename', 10) as a middleware. Also make sure that you have provided your folders paths correctly. So even if you'll get an error, then it could help you to find the reason.

Comment: I've just updated the answer (few additional stuff from the previous comment)

Comment: yeah after editing path, filename and headers, it is working now thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In documentation:

> Note: You are responsible for creating the directory when providing destination as a function. When passing a string, multer will make sure that the directory is created for you.

You provide a function as destination. I suggest you to check if folder exist in function before call callback.
Example:

```
let storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        const dir = './storage';
        if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
           fs.mkdirSync(dir);
        }
        cb(null, dir);
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname + '-' + Date.now())
    }
});
```

Comment: folder exists! even if i delete the empty folder, whenever code run and end point is hit, folder is created. but file doesn't store in that folder.